# how get image in listView Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I want add text and images in listview in android app kotlin . I have successfully parsed text in listview but failed to add images. I m also getting url of images such as url/image.jpeg but do not know how to add images in imageview in `override fun getView` .

Code :

```
  override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {

        val view : View = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row_layout,parent,false)

        val CallsingID = view.findViewById(R.id.callsign_id) as AppCompatTextView
        val StatusID = view.findViewById(R.id.airline_id) as AppCompatTextView
        val LogoAriline = view.findViewById(R.id.imageView) as ImageView


        // l have to add image here to get result 

        CallsingID.text = list[position].Callsign.toString()
        StatusID.text = list[position].Airline

        return view

}
```

Comment: try ```glide``` android lib

Answer (score 1):

```
LogoAriline.setImageResource(R.drawable.drawableName)
```

or alternatively implement Picasso http://square.github.io/picasso/

and use:

```
Picasso.with(view.context)    
    .load(R.drawable.drawableName || url)  
    .into(LogoAriline)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer . when l use your second code    ` `Picasso.get(view.context).load(R.drawable.ic_mtrl_chip_checked_black || url).into(LogoAriline)`

Comment: l got error   `too many arauments for public open fun get() picasso! defined in com.squareup.picasso.picasso`

Comment: Use `with(view.context) ` instead of `get()`

Comment: again i  have error `unresolved reference with` if l use with

Comment: `Picasso.get(with(view.context)).load(R.drawable.abc_btn_radio_material || url).into(LogoAriline)` even l have error `unresolved reference url`

Comment: `Picasso.with(view.context)    
    .load(R.drawable.drawableName || url)  
    .into(LogoAriline)`

Dont need get

Comment: and remove `|| url` from `.load()`

Comment: its same error if i use `with(view.context)` l got red line unresolved reference with

Comment: I've not got enough reputation to take this to chat so please post code again

`Picasso.with(view.context)
.load(R.drawable.abc_btn_radio_material)
.into(LogoAriline)`

Should be fine?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Glide library

```
Glide.from(convertView).load(image_source).into(LogoAriline)
```

Answer (score 0):

l find solution and his working fine without any error .

```
Picasso.get().load(list[position].logo).into(LogoAriline)
```